# IntelliJ: SpringBoot-gradle application fails with "Could not open ServletContext resource"

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, spring-boot

A spring boot application (uses gradle) setup in IntelliJ starts up properly with no exceptions. However, on hitting it with requests via browser/postman throws Internal Server Error.

The application works perfect when started from commandline via

> ./gradlew bootRun

The exception stack trace says:

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml]
>       at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:141)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)

I suspect something is not right (on classpath) when the application is started from inside IntelliJ - 14.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using a `dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml` file in a Spring Boot app?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson There is no dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml file in my whole code base.

Comment: Discovered that this does not happen when I "debug" the application from IntelliJ instead of "run".

Comment: After a couple of hours... suddenly the debug run also faces the same issue. I am not sure whats going on.